# How do I perform an expensive operation in a Singleton without waiting?

Tags: c#, .net, singleton, lazy-loading

I have created a Singleton-patterned class which contains some instance variables (Dictionaries) which are very expensive to fill.

This class is used in an .NET MVC 4 project. And they key is that the data provided by the dictionaries in this Singleton class is **nice** to have, but is not required for the web app to run.

In other words, when we process a web request, the request would be enhanced with the information from the dictionaries if they are available, but if it's not available, it's fine.

So what I would like to do is find the best way to load the data into these Dictionaries within the Singleton, without blocking the web activity as they are filled with data.

I would normally find a way to do this with multithreading, but in the past I read about and ran into problems using multithreaded techniques within ASP.NET. Have things changed in .NET 4 / MVC 4? How should I approach this?

**UPDATE**

Based on feedback below and [more research](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/19/c-system.lazylttgt-and-the-singleton-design-pattern.aspx), what I am doing now is below, and it seems to work fine. Does anyone see any potential problems? In my testing, no matter how many times I call LazySingleton.Instance, the constructor only gets called once, and returns instantly. I am able to access LazySingleton.EXPENSIVE_CACHE immediately, although it may not contain the values I am looking for (which I test for in my app using `.Contains()` call). So it seems like it's working...

If I'm only ever editing the EXPENSIVE_CACHE Dictionary from a single thread (the LazySingleton constructor), do I need to worry about thread safety when reading from it in my web app?

```
public class LazySingleton
{
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> EXPENSIVE_CACHE = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(1, 80000); // writing to cache in only one thread
    private static readonly Lazy<LazySingleton> instance = new Lazy<LazySingleton>(() => new LazySingleton());

    private LazySingleton()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => expensiveLoad());
    }

    public static LazySingleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance.Value;
        }
    }

    private void expensiveLoad()
    {
        // load data into EXPENSIVE_CACHE
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're asking how to lazy load a dictionary with values?

Comment: If it's not available, it's fine - then you don't have to approach this ;]

Comment: is the Singleton relevant to the question?

Comment: @Tejs yes, but in the specific context of .NET MVC 4.

Comment: @bas I wasn't sure if it was relevant or not. Previously we were using statically constructed objects to hold this kind of information, and only recently have moved to Singleton pattern so that things work safely outside of the ASP.NET environment.

Comment: @Adam ;-) What I meant was, we want most of the views of the web app to incorporate this information, but it's more important that the app is able start up quickly and instantly respond to requests, rather than having all of this extra data on EVERY request.

Comment: You should probably use a `Task` instead of a `Thread`

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks, just changed to that and edited my question to reflect.

Comment: Also, I think a `ConcurrentDictionary` might be in order, since you will be writing on one thread while reading from multiple threads, possibly at the same time.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks, I was considering that change, but couldn't find information on whether it's necessary when only one thread is writing, but I think I'll err on the side of caution. I've updated the question above to reflect.

Answer (score 8):

You may fill your cash repository on any of

1. Application_Start
2. Session_Start

your web application events.

 Something like this

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        SingletonCache.LoadStaticCache();
    }
</script>
```

May [this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/caching-data/caching-data-at-application-startup-cs) be useful

Comment: I appreciate the response. But wouldn't this block the application from finishing startup until the cache is finished loading, in which case it's blocking the first response to the web app until it has completed?

Comment: You will have to pay the price of cashing once. to full fill your applications integrity, i don't prefer an asynchronous solution, may be using a data base or serialization solution to save the cashed dictionary  will reduce the cost.

Comment: I guess that's the issue... I'd like to use asynchronous because in this situation, I really don't NEED the data to be loaded before my application runs. It's just that if the data is available, it's nice to refer to it.

Comment: OK that is where I was planning to go, but in the past I have had issues with multi-threading incorporated into ASP.NET, and having been burnt in the past, I'd just stayed away from it... not knowing if the situation had improved. (Much time has passed.)

Comment: I think using Application_Start and ThreadPool will be a safe solution pal, please try and inform me.

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti any results?

Comment: Yes, I updated my question subsequently with the approach we ended up taking, using a LazySingleton pattern. This seems to work very well.

Comment: Cool. Thanks 4 your reply pal. :)